# How to keep curl session alive between two php processes?

Tags: php, session, curl

I can save session and surf the website as logged user while php process exists. That is ok.

Here is my working code:

```
$options = array(
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
            CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_REFERER        => 'http://website.com/',
            CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post),

            CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . '/cookie-name',
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => '',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                'Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"',
                'Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.5"',
                'Connection: "keep-alive"',
                'Cache-Control: "max-age=0"'
            )
        );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    try {
        $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );

        if(curl_errno($ch))
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);

        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($status_code != 200)
            throw new Exception("Response with Status Code [" . $status_code . "].", 500);

    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception($ex);
    }
```

Now we have `$ch` resource to use it for other requests. But it still use curl object in one php session. What if I need to use this session in the different php processes? Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how it works)
If you want to keep session just copy `set-cookie` option from header response to some file. After that you can use this cookies for next connection. You have not to do authorization again.

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP is basically a stateless application. It's possible to reuse initialized data in other php processes by way of a database or memcache, but resource sessions will have to be re-initialized every time you start a new process.

If it is vitally important, for some reason, that you be able to use the same session, then you might consider writing a continuously running daemon that handles queued requests from the apache server in the background, accepting and responding to requests from the server in a single loop.